# Adding value to Promise Types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I've the following code that returns a promise (`{fulfilled: 'horses'}`)but before returning a Promise, I added a string value to it and my expectation was type error because `Promise <T>` type is not the same type as `T`. How does Typescript evaluates and adds 's' to the Promise object ?

```
async function asyncPluralize(s: Promise<string>): Promise<string> {
    return (await s) + 's';
}

asyncPluralize(Promise.resolve('horse'));//output {fulfilled: 'horses'}
```

Comment: await turns Promise<T> into T

Comment: I see. In that case how does the return value isn't T but rather its Promise<T> ?

Comment: Marking function as `async` makes it return a promise

Comment: You could also return `s.then(x => x + 's')`, `Promise<Promise<T>>` would get flattened to `Promise<T>`. It works a bit like `Array.flatMap`: `[1].flatMap(x => x)` is the same as `[1].flatMap(x => [x])`. One of the differences being that  `[[1]]` is not the same as `[1]` whereas `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1))` is the same as `Promise.resolve(1)`. You can look up functors and monads.

Comment: @geoffrey its already flattened, toy don't have to use `then` when you use `await`

Comment: @Konrad I meant to say `return s.then(x => x + 's')`, not `return await s.then(x => x + 's')`. This demonstrates that `then` flattens promises like `flatMap`. This fact is often  ignored by beginners because they use exclusively `async/await` which often makes things a lot more complex than they think

Comment: @WowBow I forgot to mention that it's probably not a good idea to create a `ayncPluralize` function in the first place: the point of monads is to abstracts away execution concerns and enable you to lift a synchronous function `const pluralize = (s: string) => s + 's'` into a promise when you need it to be executed asynchronously, using either `yourStrPromise.then(pluralize)` or `pluralize(await yourStrPromise)`. `async` is viral and taints your code. Better to keep most of it synchronous and pure.

Comment: @geoffrey still, op already flattened the promise